# Cerberus - Field required only when dependency is met

Tags: python, cerberus

Consider the following schema

```
schema = {
    "value_type":{
        "type": "string", "required": True
    }, 
    "units": {
        "type": "string", 
         "dependencies": {"value_type": ["float", "integer"]},
         "required": True
    }
}
```

I want the `units` field to be required **only** when the value of `value_type` field is either `float` or `integer`.

Here's the behaviour I aim to achieve

```
v = Validator(schema)
v.validate({"value_type": "float", "units": "mm"})  # 1. 
True
v.validate({"value_type": "boolean", "units": "mm"})  # 2.
False
v.validate({"value_type": "float"})  # 3.
False
v.validate({"value_type": "boolean"})  # 4.
True
```

The above Schema returns the expected result only for the first 3 cases.

If I change the definition of `units` (by omitting the `"required": True`) to

```
"units": {"type": "string", "dependencies": {"value_type": ["float", "integer"]}}
```

then the validation of

```
v.validate({"value_type": "float"})  # 3.
True
```

returns `True` which is not what I want.

I took a look at `oneof` rules in the [documentation](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#of-rules) but couldn't find a way to apply this only to the `required` property.

I want the value of required to be `True` only when the dependency is met.

How should I modify my schema to achieve this?

Comment: Which version are you using? I can't replicate the behaviour of the fourth example with the current's `master` branch HEAD. I get this error: `{'units': ['required field']}`.

Comment: @funky-future, version is 1.2. Apologies if it is confusing; The example shows the behaviour I want to achieve. 
I also get the same error when running this.

Comment: so, what does "The above Schema returns the expected result only for the first 3 cases." mean?

Comment: @funky-future, I mean that, the way that `schema` is defined, I get the results that I want (case 1: T, case 2: F, case 3: F) for the first three cases, but not for the fourth(in case 4, I want to get True but instead I get the error about the fields being required)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your variations span more than one field, the `*of` rules aren't exactly suited, especially since these seem to be top-level fields in the document.

I would generally advise that there's still Python and not everything must be expressed with a schema, so you can simply define two valid schemas and test against these:

```
schema1 = {...}
schema2 = {...}

if not any(validator(document, schema=x) for x in (schema1, schema2)):
    boom()
```

This is also better comprehendable than any schema you would end up with.

Alternatively, you could use the `check_with` rule. The example shows two different ways to submit an error, where the latter one is prefable when the errors are only presented to humans, as they allow custom messages for different situations while lacking structural information about the error:

```
class MyValidator(Validator):
    def _check_with_units_required(self, field, value):
        if value in ("float", "integer"):
            if "units" not in self.document:
                self._error("units", errors.REQUIRED_FIELD, "check_with")
        else:
            if "units" in self.document:
                self._error(
                    "units", "The 'units' field must not be provided for value "
                             "types other than float or integer."
                )

schema = {
    "value_type": {
        "check_with": "units_required",
        "required": True,
        "type": "string"
    },
    "units": {
        "type": "string",
    }
}

validator = MyValidator(schema)

assert validator({"value_type": "float", "units": "mm"})
assert not validator({"value_type": "boolean", "units": "mm"})
assert not validator({"value_type": "float"})
assert validator({"value_type": "boolean"})
```

Comment: Being able to express the relations without  having to write "code" is kind of a requirement in my case, but I see your point about readability and comprehensibility.

Comment: @helplessKirk Sure, there are often cases where everything should be lumped together in a schema. In this case I suggest to make use of the `check_with` rule, this way one can also use non-generic error messages, which are often more suited to point out what the problem is to users.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for the `check_with` rule. Do you think you could add an example so I can accept the answer too?

Comment: @helplessKirk i added that example.

Comment: @funky-future, thanks! You have saved my day! Works like a charm. Was searching Cerberus docs for about 3 hours to find an answer for the same use case.